# How to configure an Azure Functions (C#) project in GitHub to be deployed automatically?

Tags: github, deployment, azure-functions, kudu

I created an Azure Functions 2.0 (C#) project in VS 2017 and put it in GitHub. If I publish to Azure directly from VS, it works just fine. Then I accessed Azure Portal in order to configure Azure Functions, and there is this option to deploy from GitHub. I configured this option and when I commit something to GitHub, the Azure Portal detects and start some process (in Deployment Center there are logs with "success" status for each change I made in GitHub) but the code isn't deployed.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to build a CI/CD using Azure DevOps from my understanding, did you setup a pipeline Build/Release?

Comment: did you use the kudu or azure pipeline preview?

Comment: Is this the guide you're trying to follow? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment#set-up-continuous-deployment.

Comment: Did you configure the right branch?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your anwsers!

@AnassKartit, I'm not using Azure DevOps. I am using Kudu (because aparently it's simple). I am using as guide exactly the link posted by brettsam, but is not working.

LiMubei, yes, it's configured to master. In fact, in Azure Portal, my commits are detected and, when I check Deployment Center, I see logs saying the deploy was successfully made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, guys! I found the problem! I first published my solution directly from Visual Studio to Azure. Then, all functions became read-only, so build process did executed with success, but the files aren't updated.

I erased my functions app and recreated manually, and configured deployment with Kudu, getting from GitHub, and then everything works like a charm! Each commit in github updates my app!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Visual Studio is connected to GitHub to push the azure function

[image]

In the deployement center , you need to check that deployement is connected to github

[image: Fetching github code]

You also need to check the Azure function version 2.

[image: Azure function version]

Step by steps guide Referenced from my article 
[Continuous Azure function deployement from Github using Kudu Build Server](https://builtwithcloud.com/continuous-azure-function-deployement-from-github-using-kudu-build-server/)

Comment: Thank you! I already found the problem. My functions were read-only, because my first publication was from Visual Studio, and then the build process couldn't update the files!